# Is there a way in Postman to change xml2Json conversion rules?

Tags: json, xml, postman, xml-to-json

I have some instances where I need to convert my XML response, and in multiple cases I have nodes that appear **once or more** times.
If it looks like this **bbb** will be just another element:

```
<aaa>
 <bbb>ccc</bbb>
</aaa>
```

and to get **ccc** value I have to access json like this: `pm.response.json().aaa.bbb`

But if XML looks something like this **bbb** will become array:

```
<aaa>
 <bbb>ccc</bbb>
 <bbb>ddd</bbb>
</aaa>
```

and to get **ccc** value I have to access json like this: `pm.response.json().aaa.bbb[0]`

Later on, when I use JSON data I need to always check whether I have one or multiple elements returned from provider. What I want is to avoid checking `Array.isArray...` all the time and force it to be array. Is there is such option?

Comment: Is there any way that you could use the built in XML convertor to help you? `var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);` This is the syntax from the examples on the Docs. I don’t fully understand the question to give a better response.

Comment: I am using var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);, that is the problem. By default it doesn't distinguish potential arrays, if it gets response with only one bbb it will convert it to regular element while it will be array if there are more... Corrected the question a little bit to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

I have created this group of functions, I hope they can help you (I think that `transformIntoSingleElement` is what you are looking for):

```
function stackTrace() {
    var err = new Error();
    console.log(err.stack);
    return err;
}
function transformIntoArray(element, mandatory){
    mandatory = (mandatory!==undefined)?mandatory:true;
    if(element === undefined && mandatory){
        stackTrace();
        return element;
    }
    if(element === undefined)
        return [];
    if(element.constructor.name != "Array")
        return [element];
    return element;
}
function transformIntoSingleElement(element, index, mandatory){
    mandatory = (mandatory!==undefined)?mandatory:true;
    if(element === undefined && mandatory){
        stackTrace();
        return element;
    }
    if(element === undefined){
        return element;
    }
    if(element.constructor.name == "Array"){
        if(element.length >= index)
            return element[index];
        return element[0];
    }
    return element;
}
function getElementValue(element, dflt, mandatory){
    dflt = dflt || "";
    mandatory = (mandatory!==undefined)?mandatory:true;
    if(element === undefined && mandatory){
        stackTrace();
        return element;
    }
    if(element === undefined)
        return dflt;
    if(element._ === undefined)
        return element;
    return element._;
}
function getAttributeValue(element, attribute, dflt, mandatory){
    dflt = dflt || "";
    mandatory = (mandatory!==undefined)?mandatory:true;
    if(element === undefined && mandatory){
        stackTrace();
        return element;
    }
    if(element.$ !== undefined && element.$[attribute] !== undefined && (element.$[attribute] !== "" || (element.$[attribute] === "" && mandatory))){
        return element.$[attribute];
    }
    return dflt;
}
```